# Connection failure node js to progress db without odbc connection (Using trireme)

Tags: java, node.js, apigee, openedge, progress-db

I am able to connect progress db using node js with odbc connection. But, I am unable to connect without odbc connection. I found a node js module which helps to make this connection but it shows some errors like.

> C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\trireme-jdbc\lib\trireme-jdbc.js:36
>   throw new Error('trireme-jdbc does not appear to be running on
>   Trireme.'+ e);   ^
>
> Error: trireme-jdbc does not appear to be running on Trireme.Error: No
>   such module: trireme-jdbc-wrap
>       at Object. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\trireme-jdbc\lib\trireme-jdbc.js:36:9)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\creddyga\eclipse workspace\core java\src\com\jci\node\nodeTrireme.js:1:74)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

By above errors i understood: `trireme-jdbc-wrap` module needs to be installed.
During module installation using npm the error i am facing is 'trireme-jdbc-wrap' is not in npm registery.

I used following link for making this connection: https://github.com/apigee/trireme-jdbc

MY code:

```
var jdbc = require('C:/Program    Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/node_modules/trireme-jdbc');

var db = new jdbc.Database({
   url: 'url for db conn',
  properties: {
   user: 'username',
   password: 'password',
 },
  minConnections: 1,
  maxConnections: 20,
  idleTimeout: 100
});

db.execute('SELECT person FROM person',
      function(err, result, rows) {
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
          console.log('Row: %j', row);
     });
});
```

Please suggest some solution for Using trireme (or) any other new modules related to node js.